# Pegar a semana corretamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Colegas,

Como eu faria para pegar a semana de um determinado mês? Por exemplo: se na semana que vem o usuário acessar o sistema (hoje é dia 18/11/16), apareceria:

> Semana corrente:  dia 20/11/2016 a 27/11/2016

Aceito sugestões em PHP, Jquery ou Javascript.

Obrigado

Comment: Seria isso ? `date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 week"));`

Answer (score 1):

Para adicionar esse sistema em PHP é simples.

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 week"));
```

Usando esse código você vai pegar a data atual e adicionar uma semana a mais nela (`+1 week`).

Acessando hoje, a saída será

> 25-11-2016

Daí então para ficar como você quer, basta fazer

```
echo date('d-m-Y')." à ". date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 week"));
```

> 18/11/2016 à 25/11/2016

Leitura sugerida: [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)

Uma alternativa também é utilizar Javascript.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
```

Adicionar 7 dias a mais da data atual.

Leitura sugerida: [SetDate();](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp)

Comment: Perfeito Mauro, só tenho uma dúvida. Vamos supor que o usuário acesse no dia 22/11/2016. Como faria para que aparecesse 20/11/2016 a 27/11/2016?

Comment: Dai você teria que fazer uma verificação da data (22/11). Mas poderia explicar o porque, para que eu possa implementar e te passar ?

Comment: para um relatório da semana corrente

Comment: é fixo, sempre no dia 22 ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
var primeiroDia = moment().startOf('isoWeek').toDate();
var ultimoDia = moment().endOf('isoWeek').toDate();

console.log(primeiroDia);
console.log(ultimoDia);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/FLhpq/6854/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Feito em js Puro

```
  var dataHoje = new Date(); //Pegar a data atual
    var diaSemana = dataHoje.getDay(); //Pegar o dia da semana
    var diaSemana = 7 - dataHoje; //Quantidade de dias que faltam para terminar a semana
    var primeiroDia = new Date(dataHoje.setDate(dataHoje.getDate() + dias)); //Primeiro dia da semana que vem
    var ultimoDia = new Date(dataHoje.setDate(primeiroDia.getDate() + 7)); //Segundo dia da semana que vem
```